# record.clone().clone() instead of .clone()?

Tags: apex, clone, platform-bug

We are using Andrew Fawcett's [SObjectDataloader Library](https://github.com/afawcett/apex-sobjectdataloader) where I fixed a couple things and stumbled over odd behavior that I couldn't find valid explanation for.

So in the Library, records are extracted from a Json and then cloned to be inserted with a new id ([line 496](https://github.com/afawcett/apex-sobjectdataloader/blob/048e80ac71a52fc914dbe0d92b8b8e4f8d298433/apex-sobjectdataloader/src/classes/SObjectDataLoader.cls#L496)). But not with `obj.clone()`, but like this: `obj.clone().clone()`.

I assumed this happend by accident and removed one of them. Worked as expected.
But when I pushed the changes to our Patch org, I got internal Salesforce errors from inserting the clone.

> Unable to Access Page

**What is .clone().clone() doing different than .clone()?**

**Why did it only fail in the patch org?**

Comment: You probably should ask SonalJ who made that change. https://github.com/afawcett/apex-sobjectdataloader/commit/0ae1aba3b4025b14aca934c006493866f68a23b7